# Which collection C# for person objs + grouping regex matches

Tags: c#, database, performance, collections, iteration

I'm working on a piece of code that will store and sort through a collection of person objects, with properties: First name, Last name, and Id.

I wish to use a generic collection that will iterate/store and sort these objs. I've been leaning towards `SortedDictionary` class to achieve this. I am aware that there are other options, namely, `SortedList`, or `Dictionary` (also aware the `Dictionary` will not sort, at least not by itself).

The ideal key would be the `Id` (of type `String`), but I have no guarantee that they are all unique, and the data is being retrieved from DB, so there is also the possibility of human error, (the id is not the pk of the table).

And as far as the value, I wish to store an array/list of the objects themselves. So when I pull a key from the collection, I will get a complete reference of that person (name + id).

Now I also wish to group objs in this list based on a regex match (last and first name duplicates), and the first thing that comes to my inexperienced mind, is iterating through the collection (two for loops, iterating through two collections, which would be expensive as the data increases). Aside from what the ideal collection would be I also would like to know if there are other efficient ways of grouping this dups, in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want here is to use some form of LINQ (not LINQ to SQL, as it is a bastardization of a DAL and LINQ).

You can store the information in XML, for example, and use LINQ to XML. The information can be gathered as Entities and use LINQ to Entities. You can also use LINQ to Objects with any collection that uses IEnumerable. A simple list will work.

Going at it this way, you don't have to worry about creating some type of derived key to query the group of objects, or sort them. You can simply pull the object collection and then slice, dice, filter, etc. however you desire.

And, yes, you can combine Regex with LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882639.aspx